# Editing of material such as PDFs in iOS for Vizualisation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, pdf

*This thread is a part of the major thread about using iPad for education purposes [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74399/how-to-read-and-write-with-ipad-ipad-for-studying-required-styluses-and-apps).*

Editing is slightly ambiguous term but here it means things such as collages [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage), merging, annotation and such things. I define this term here by purpose openly to categorize different threads that usually addresses PDFs but possible other similar threads in Apple SE.

> So how can I do the editing in iOS?

The goal is to make some material visually-more-accessible so the word may contain things such as certain graphs and analysis things.

Answer (score 1):

I have outlined the things in three categories Input, Writing and Visualization. You see a picture or a homework, you see it i.e. you store it to your brains -- or you can scan it with your iPad or iPhone. You realize you want to add some material to it so you may add a photo -- vizualisation -- or write something.

**I. Input**

> I. Readdle Scanner: photocopy & edit to adjust lightness etc and to store physical
>
> II. Mathematical Apps such as Quick Graph, Sage Math and TouchDraw to process mostly mathematical ideas
>
> III. Conceptual tools such as general-graph-tool iThoughtsHD and linguistic-analysis-tools such as Wordflex
>
> > [image]

**II. Writing**

> **Text Processing**
>
> > I. TeX Writer
> >
> > II. Business apps such as Pages, Numbers and Keynotes to generate things fast
>
> **Annotation**
>
> > I. PDFPen (if you need only merging, check PDF Merger)
> >
> > II. PDFExpert
> >
> > III. GoodReader (somewhat limited editing tools)

**III. Vizualisation**

> **Image Processing**
>
> > I. ProCreate
> >
> > II. Echograph for generating short GIF videos from images
>
> **Collage**
>
> > I have tried most collage apps in iPad and iPhone but I only like the following
> >
> > > I. MyFrames app
> > >
> > > II. FrameArstist app
> >
> > Somewhat-marketed apps such as Layout have bugs in writing and developer not responding and apparently not developing anymore.

**Summarum**

> Personally, I use a massive amount of different editing tools. You can see some results [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/204393#204393). It is sometimes slow when missing the right tool but generally I really like doing one thing well even though it may take a bit more time.
>
> It is pretty easy: you see something, you process it somehow and in every step you may need a specific app for your purpose. For brainstorming, you may want to have a look in `input` part while editor may want to look at `vizualization` part and `writing` part. I use the above tools but my tools will change because the environment changes. When I started with iOS, I had no OSx but later I got it making some steps easier -- however I am able to write long essays with photos and graphs in iOS without touching a proper desktop. It is not however the most efficient way of doing things so I use nowadays iOS besides OSx.